# Laravel: Using try...catch with DB::transaction()

Tags: php, laravel, transactions

We all use `DB::transaction()` for multiple insert queries. In doing so, should a `try...catch` be placed inside it or wrapping it? Is it even necessary to include a `try...catch` when a transaction will automatically fail if something goes wrong?

Sample `try...catch` wrapping a transaction:

```
// try...catch
try {
    // Transaction
    $exception = DB::transaction(function() {

        // Do your SQL here

    });

    if(is_null($exception)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new Exception;
    }

}
catch(Exception $e) {
    return false;
}
```

The opposite, a `DB::transaction()` wrapping a try...catch:

```
// Transaction
$exception = DB::transaction(function() {
    // try...catch
    try {

        // Do your SQL here

    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }

});

return is_null($exception) ? true : false;
```

Or simply a transaction w/o a try...catch

```
// Transaction only
$exception = DB::transaction(function() {

    // Do your SQL here

});

return is_null($exception) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 303, accepted):

In the case you need to manually 'exit' a transaction through code (be it through an exception or simply checking an error state) you shouldn't use `DB::transaction()` but instead wrap your code in `DB::beginTransaction` and `DB::commit`/`DB::rollback()`:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    DB::insert(...);
    DB::insert(...);
    DB::insert(...);

    DB::commit();
    // all good
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    // something went wrong
}
```

See the [transaction docs](http://laravel.com/docs/database#database-transactions).

Comment: What's the difference between `DB::beginTransaction()` and `DB:transaction()` ?

Comment: `DB::transaction` accepts an anonymous function for the DB statements to run inside the transaction, `DB::beginTransaction()` requires the DB statements to be written 'next to' the invocation (as per the example above) and then a final `DB::commit()` or `DB::rollback()` to finish the transaction off.

Comment: Simple question : What happen if you don't do a rollback after exception , or if you don't catch exception ? Auto rollback after the end of the script ?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea, but yes I would imagine that the transaction stays open, happily swallowing up further DB inserts/updates and then finally when the application ends, the whole thing is rolled back. It would be quite easy to throw together a quick test script to try it out. You may find you get a "transaction not exited" style exception as well as an automatic rollback.

Comment: Laravel5.3 Database Transaction is a big issue it really not work

Comment: @HengSopheak this question was about Laravel 4 databases so it's quite possible my answer is no longer correct for 5.3. It might be worth you asking a new question with the Laravel 5.3 tag to get the right community support.

Comment: i have try much about Laravel5.3.19 on DB transaction but it simply not work as well and now I try it more time to valid my practice and I have really more tutorial about this cause but they said is not bug. give me try again. but I really sure with this cause because i have update LR framework with latest version via company update and install

Comment: i use Db:commit as if doesn't work, how can make it working

Comment: FYI we're currently using this pattern successfully with Laravel 5.5.

Comment: dont forget to rethrow the exception or else your migration will look 'completed' to the runner and the entry will be placed in your `migrations` table

Comment: Can I use Eloquent operations inside the Try? That will rollback?

Comment: After 2hrs of pulling out my hair I have discovered that my table engine is MyISAM.

Comment: @alexrussell don't you think DB::commit(); should be outside of try. `DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    DB::insert(...);

    // all good
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    // something went wrong
}    DB::commit();`

Comment: To me, no. If something goes wrong during the commit, we may still want to try to roll back. That said, this is a very old answer to an old Laravel question and I haven't done PHP proper in a few years now, so I'm certainly not any authority on this any more. It may not even be possible to roll back from an exception raised during commit, so it may have to go outside, though be sure not to call `commit` after `rollback` too, which you would if you _only_ move commit to after the `try/catch` and had an exception during the `try` part.

Comment: @alexrussell ... If exception occur in try block then control goes in catch and rollback command will execute. and even if after catch block error (before commit statement)  the result of sql query in try block will not save in db as the sql statement is is transaction block. Right??

Comment: Yeah a rollback will "cancel" the transaction. But then the code will try to to call "commit" I dunno if that'll error itself (nothing to commit/not in a transaction) or whether it'll be a no-op. Just warning you you might want to ensure commit isn't called after rollback if it would error in any way.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you use `DB::transaction()` instead inside of a try block with a catch block afterwards?

Answer (score 42):

If you use PHP7, use [Throwable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php) in `catch` for catching user exceptions and fatal errors.

For example:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    DB::insert(...);    
    DB::commit();
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

If your code must be compartable with PHP5, use `Exception` and `Throwable`:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    DB::insert(...);    
    DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    throw $e;
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: What about the fact that DB::beginTransaction() may also throws \Exception? Should it be included in the try/catch?

Comment: If transaction has not been started, we do not need to rollback anything. Moreother, it is no good to try rollback not started transaction in `catch` block. Therefore good place for `DB::beginTransaction()` is before `try` block.

Answer (score 24):

You could wrapping the transaction over try..catch or even reverse them,
here my example code I used to in laravel 5,, if you look deep inside `DB:transaction()` in `Illuminate\Database\Connection` that the same like you write manual transaction.

**Laravel Transaction**

```
public function transaction(Closure $callback)
    {
        $this->beginTransaction();

        try {
            $result = $callback($this);

            $this->commit();
        }

        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->rollBack();

            throw $e;
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            $this->rollBack();

            throw $e;
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

so you could write your code like this, and handle your exception like throw message back into your form via flash or redirect to another page. REMEMBER return inside closure is returned in transaction() so if you return `redirect()->back()` it won't redirect immediately, because the it returned at variable which handle the transaction.

**Wrap Transaction**

```
try {
    $result = DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $message) {
        // execute query 1
        // execute query 2
        // ..
    });          
    // redirect the page
    return redirect(route('account.article'));
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

then the alternative is throw boolean variable and handle redirect outside transaction function or if your need to retrieve why transaction failed you can get it from `$e->getMessage()` inside `catch(Exception $e){...}`

Comment: I used transaction without try-catch block and It worked well too

Comment: @hamidrezasamsami yes, the database automatic rolled back, but sometime you need to know are the queries all succeed or not..

Comment: The "Wrap Transaction" example is wrong.  This will always commit, even if one of the queries failed because all exceptions are caught within the transaction callback.  You want to put the try/catch outside of DB::transaction.

Comment: After the "Wrap Transaction" code was updated on Jan 20, 2022 to reflect @redmallard's suggestion, I feel that this should be the correct answer. Also I think that the Exception/Throwable dichotomy is mostly a waste of time, so write all of my handlers as `catch(\Exception $e){...}` with the leading backslash to prevent ambiguity. It seems that \Throwable is meant more for framework internals, but if someone has a legitimate use case, it would be helpful to comment here

Comment: But DB::beginTransaction also throws a Throwable, so based on that, shouldn't it also be inside the try {}?

Answer (score 10):

I've decided to give an answer to this question because I think it can be solved using a simpler syntax than the convoluted try-catch block. The Laravel documentation is pretty brief on this subject.

Instead of using try-catch, you can just use the `DB::transaction(){...}` wrapper like this:

```php
// MyController.php
public function store(Request $request) {
    return DB::transaction(function() use ($request) {
        $user = User::create([
            'username' => $request->post('username')
        ]);

        // Add some sort of "log" record for the sake of transaction:
        $log = Log::create([
            'message' => 'User Foobar created'
        ]);

        // Lets add some custom validation that will prohibit the transaction:
        if($user->id > 1) {
            throw AnyException('Please rollback this transaction');
        }

        return response()->json(['message' => 'User saved!']);
    });
};
```

You should see that in this setup the User and the Log record cannot exist without eachother.

Some notes on the implementation above:

- Make sure to `return` anything the transaction, so that you can use the `response()` you return within its callback as the response of the controller.
- Make sure to `throw` an exception if you want the transaction to be rollbacked (or have a nested function that throws the exception for you automatically, like any SQL exception from within Eloquent).
- The `id`, `updated_at`, `created_at` and any other fields are AVAILABLE AFTER CREATION for the `$user` object (for the duration of this transaction at least). The transaction will run through any of the creation logic you have. HOWEVER, the whole record is discarded when `SomeCustomException` is thrown. An auto-increment column for `id` does get incremented though on failed transactions.

**Tested on Laravel 5.8**

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Laravel 8 and you should wrap the transaction in a try-catch as follows:

```
try {
    DB::transaction(function () {
        // Perform your queries here using the models or DB facade
    });
}
catch (\Throwable $e) {
    // Do something with your exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 8, you can use DB::transaction in try-catch.
for example :

```
try{
    DB::transaction(function() {
        // do anything
    });
}
catch(){
    // do anything
}
```

if each query fails on try, the catch block be run.

**New update on November 18, 2023. Answer to the [Carlos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9769322/carlos)'s comment**

You don't need to use "DB::rollback" in the catch block because if an exception is thrown within the transaction closure, the transaction will automatically be rolled back and the exception will be re-thrown. If you want to handle "DB::rollback" in the catch block, it's better to use transactions manually:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    DB::update('update users set votes = 1');
    DB::delete('delete from posts');
    //if everything goes well
    DB::commit();
    
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //if something goes wrong
    DB::rollback();
}
```

You can follow [Laravel Documents](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database#database-transactions).

Comment: Can I use "DB::rollback" in catch despite the fact that there is no a transaction there? or for using that I need to move "DB:transaction" before "try"?

Comment: I edited my post to answer Carlos's comment.

Answer (score 1):

First: using **PostgreSQL** database in Laravel makes things more tricky.

If you don't rollback after a transaction error, each futher queries  will throw this error *In failed sql transaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block*. So if you can't save original error message in a table BEFORE the rollback.

```
try {
    DB::beginTransaction(); //start transaction
    $user1 = User::find(1);
    $user1->update(['money' => 'not_a_number']); //bad update
}
catch(Exception $exception) {
    $user2 = User::find(2); // ko, "In failed sql transaction" error
    $user2->update(['field' => 'value']);
}

try {
    DB::beginTransaction(); //start transaction
    $user1 = User::find(1);
    $user1->update(['money' => 'not_a_number']); //bad update
}
catch(Exception $exception) {
    DB::rollBack();
    $user2 = User::find(2); // ok, go on
    $user2->update(['field' => 'value']);
}
```

Second: pay attention to Eloquent model attributes system.

Eloquent model keeps changed attributes after an update error, so if we want to update that model inside the catch block, we need to discard bad attributes. This isn't a dbtransaction affair, so the rollback command is useless.

```
try {
    DB::beginTransaction(); //start transaction
    $user1 = User::find(1);
    $user1->update(['money' => 'not_a_number']); //bad update
}
catch(Exception|Error $exception) {
    DB::rollBack();
    $user1->update(['success' => 'false']); // ko, bad update again
}

try {
    DB::beginTransaction(); //start transaction
    $user1 = User::find(1);
    $user1->update(['money' => 'not_a_number']); //bad update
}
catch(Exception|Error $exception) {
    DB::rollBack();
    $user1->discardChanges(); // remove attribute changes from model
    $user1->update(['success' => 'false']); // ok, go on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you head over to your config/database.php and change the engine to InnoDB.

over MyISAM which is the default engine for MySQL database MyISAM supports transactions. adding it in through the config will ensure that all table created afterwards will have it as default.

```
  <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

  // Other settings we don't care about.

    'connections' => [
      
        // Other connections we don't care about

        'mysql' => [
            // Other mysql configurations we don't care about
            'engine' => 'InnoDB',
        ],
    ]
];
```