# Eloquent lastInsertId

Tags: php, oop, orm, eloquent

I want to get 'loan_id' that was inserted in both tables.

With `return $this->getConnection()->getPdo()->lastInsertId();`
I suppose i should get at least last id (which is specified for this model as 'id' and autoincremented) but I don't receive it too. (just empty response)

Even better if I can get full object that was inserted in DB.

So, I wanted to catch an Exception if transaction fails and return error message in case of failure and $loan_id or saved Object in case of success. how to do it ?

```php
<?php
namespace App\model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Manager as Manager;
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;
use PDO;

class Loan extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'loans';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function addLoan($amount, $instalments)
    {

        // Manager::connection()->getPdo()->beginTransaction();
        $this->getConnection()->transaction(function () use ($amount)
        {
            $loan_id = substr(uniqid(), -12);

            DB::table('loans')->insert([
                    'loan_id' => $loan_id,
                    'amount' => $amount,
                    'status' => 'requested'
                ]
            );

            DB::table('loan_instalment')->insert([
                    'loan_id' => $loan_id,
                    'principal' => 777.12,
                    'interest' => 333.12
                ]
            );

        });

        return $this->getConnection()->getPdo()->lastInsertId();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you have two inserts. you'd only ever be able to get the id from `loan_instalment`, since  last_insert() only ever returns ONE single id, from the last insert performed.

Comment: yes, i understand that. But i don't get any Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
$this->getConnection()->getPdo()->lastInsertId()
```

You can do this:

```
DB::table('table')->insert([...])->lastInsertId();
```

And catching an exception see: [Laravel: Using try...catch with DB::transaction()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906844/laravel-using-try-catch-with-dbtransaction)

Comment: insert->lastInsertId() didn't work. Instead of insert this worked: insertGetId

Comment: both lastInsertId and insertGetId can't be called fluently after insert([]...).