# Laravel 5.3 did not roll back if DB::transaction throws an error?

Tags: database, laravel

I tried to make a db transaction when I made multi queries.

and also I tried to catch the exceptions outside the transaction just like

```
DB::transaction(function() {
   try{
        //....db queries
   }catch(\Exception $e){
        Log::info($e);
   }
});
```

when some exceptions thrown here, the transaction seems like not be rolled back, the data has been changed in the database.

If I do `DB::rollBack()` in the catch statement manually, all my data will be fine,

it makes me think if I have to do `DB::rollBack()` manually?

but I do remember the doc of Laravel said if I am using `DB::transaction` to manage my db queries, when the exceptions threw, `DB::rollBack()` will be executed automatically?

It has been changed in Laravel 5.3?

Comment: also show your proper code to make your question more clear

Comment: @msonowal I just wanna discuss the logic of the DB::transaction, not an exact code. it's easy to understand what i am talking about if you do know Laravel, so I don't think I have to type so many code to make my point clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906844/laravel-using-try-catch-with-dbtransaction). you shouldn't use `DB::transaction()` but instead wrap your code in `DB::beginTransaction` and `DB::commit/DB::rollback()`

Hope this work for you!

Comment: so whether I should use the DB::beginTransaction rather than DB::transaction? If yes, when the DB::transaction will be used? seems like the DB::transaction is unnecessary.

Comment: @AbelLee: If you would like to begin a transaction manually and have complete control over rollbacks and commits, you may use the `beginTransaction` method,  [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#database-transactions).

Comment: I just wanna catch the exceptions in the transaction, also the origin behaviors of the transaction will be executed. cause of not all of the transactions are right absolutely. If so, the DB::transaction is not so better than DB::beginTransaction

Answer (score 2):

If You have multiple table entries and update depending on each Other .it is advised that you should use Transactions

```
$var_name = DB::transaction(function () {
//    DB operations.....
});
```

$var_name returns null when successful

for further details please refer to the doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database

Hope this Helps you.
Ask in case any query

Comment: thanks in advanced, I have read the doc, but I think the doc is not so detailed. It just told me how to use DB::transaction and the DB::rollBack() will be executed in a normal transaction way but I have did try...catch manually, they never mentioned.

Comment: you might be getting a different error because i myself was working on db transaction and i didnt need try catch..please check once

Comment: some normal situation just 500, I do know this. I just wanna know whether I have to do DB::rollBack() manually when I wrapped a "try...catch" outside the db queries.

Comment: The reason why I got the error, cause of I haven't submit a non-nullable column to the mysql, If I do not wrap a "try...catch", it will show me a db error but 500 error for the frontend when I was in the debug mode.

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.3, I found if I don't rollback manually, it will be some weird performance in mysql, I guess whether cause of the transaction is multi-thread? because I found I if do "try...catch" in the transaction, all queries will be executed no matter what any exceptions or not. the id column will be updated sometimes or some entried will be deleted but one entry will be saved if I do deletion and creation queries together in the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

it will not be executed automatically if you're implementing like that,
but if you use it as a closure like below

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    //db queries
});
```

It will be rollbacked automatically.

Comment: I have tried that like you have posted, I even don't know the DB::rollBack() whether be excuted, it just throw out a "500" error code if some exceptions occurred in the DB::transaction. so I wanna wrap a "try...catch" to make the exceptions comfortable. And if I do this, I found I have to DB::rollBack() manually :(

Answer (score 0):

The proper way with transactions and `try/catch` is like this:

```
try {
    DB::transaction(function(){
        //your query stuff here
    });

    DB::commit(); //transactions had no error
} catch (\Exception $e ) {
    //transactions had an error
    DB::rollback();

    //do something with $e->getMessage();
}
```

The purpose is to give you greater control in the event that your queries fail. This way, you can catch the exception and roll the transaction back. Otherwise, you'd just perform the transaction.