# How to execute a block of php code if a transaction using eloquent fails (Laravel 5.3)?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to remove the directory that gets created when I record in the database is inserted. I have something like this.

```
$model->dir = MyClass->createDirectory();

\DB::transaction(function(){ 
    $model->save(); // fails        
});
MyClass->removeDirectory(); //this will be execute upon failure.
```

I'm not asking about try catch block with transactions. I am asking how to execute a block of code if transaction fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: Using try...catch with DB::transaction()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906844/laravel-using-try-catch-with-dbtransaction)

Comment: I'm not asking about try catch block with transactions. I am asking how to execute a block of code if transaction fails.

Comment: It's the same thing but in your case in the `catch` block execute a block of code that you want ! or am i messing something?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the directory created after `rollback` in the transaction using `try catch`.

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try{

    $model->save();

    DB::commit();

}catch(\Exception $e){

    DB::rollback();

   // After rollback delete directory created
   // write code to delete directory here.
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the DB::beginTrasaction() specifying a connection name because I'm not using the default connection when using eloquent.

Comment: Have you some problem with default connection ?

Comment: I don't use ORMs very often so I created a different connection with slightly different parameters to execute the eloquent commands.

Comment: But, I'm not familiar with those ways. Other might know best of luck.