# Lavavel/Eloquent 5 transactions rolling back not backing save

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I do seem to be having problems getting database transactions to work on a model. I've referred to related posts on SO, but no luck yet.

In my example, I create a new record in the DB.  I should be able to rollback and the new record should have disappeared shouldn't it?

```
        try{
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $oNewMap = $oMap->replicate();
            $oNewMap->name = "[test] " . $oNewMap->name;
            $oNewMap->save();  // works

            DB::rollBack();  / /record still in db
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){       
            DB::rollBack();
            /* Transaction failed. */
        }
```

When the rollback occured, why wouldn't the saved record disappear from the DB?  Am I missing something with how models work with transactions?

The physical tables are all InnoDB, btw.

[EDITTED: to simplify the problem to a simple save and rollback, not doing two saves where the second save violates an FK constraint.]

Comment: Have you checked transaction status?

Comment: @GaurangJoshi Check it where?

Comment: Does `DB::rollback();` definitely get executed?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes, the exception is definitely thrown.

Comment: Can you wrap the whole transaction in `\DB::enableQueryLog(); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());` and post the result?

Comment: Does the model use a different database connection?

Comment: The models have their own named database connection.

Comment: The models have their own database connection.  I think that's where the problem is.  @JonasStaudenmeir, can you please post an answer that you need to explicitly specify on which connection the transaction lives on?  I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Try wrapping the `try catch` inside `transaction`. In this method use  `DB::commit()` to save the transaction. If `commit()` is not used, then the records won't be saved. Refer this [S.O. Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906844/laravel-using-try-catch-with-dbtransaction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the model doesn't use the default database connection, you have to specify it on the transaction:

```
DB::connection('name')->beginTransaction();
DB::connection('name')->commit();
DB::connection('name')->rollBack();
```

Comment: That did it.  There was multiple database connections unbeknownst to me.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing your question, i remember a long time ago, where I had the same problem.

In the end i found out, that the function is called `rollBack` and not `rollback` - Note the capitalized B

Comment: Good catch!  Changed it and it didn't appear to make a difference.  Wonder why it didn't barf on DB::rollback(), tho.

Answer (score 1):

Check your transaction level and conform that you are working with single `beginTransaction()` so, might you will find solution perfectly.

```
DB::beginTransaction()
DB::beginTransaction()
DB::transactionLevel() // will return 2
DB::commit() // doesn't commit
DB::transactionLevel() // will return 1
DB::commit() // finally, it commits to the database
DB::transactionLevel() // will return 0
```