# Laravel transaction does not rollback when none db exception happens

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, transactions

Here is my code:

```
 DB::transaction(function () use ($r, $certificate, $candidate) {

             UserCertificate::create([
                 'user_id' => $r['user_id'],
                 'certificate_id' => $certificate->id,
                 'issue_date' => Carbon::now()
              ]);

             // create badge
             $this->createCandidateBadge($candidate, $certificate);

});
```

An exception happens while creating the candidate badge: `$this->createCandidateBadge`

But when I see `user_certificates` table there is a certificate created! I don't want to create a certificate in DB unless a badge created successfully!

Comment: use try catch and make manual process for commit rollbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make customized transaction functionality and manual commit and rollbacks using try and catch blocks like this:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try{
        UserCertificate::create([
             'user_id' => $r['user_id'],
             'certificate_id' => $certificate->id,
             'issue_date' => Carbon::now()
          ]);

         // create badge
         $this->createCandidateBadge($candidate, $certificate);

         DB::commit();

}catch (\Exception $e){
    DB::rollBack();
}
```

In case of exception of any type, it will be catched and then all db operations will be rollbacked. In case of no exception data will be saved.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [Database Transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#database-transactions),

> If an exception is thrown within the transaction Closure, the
>   transaction will automatically be rolled back.

You should try to wrap your logic inside the `DB::transaction` by the `try...catch`, as follows:

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($r, $certificate, $candidate) {
    try {
         UserCertificate::create([
             'user_id' => $r['user_id'],
             'certificate_id' => $certificate->id,
             'issue_date' => Carbon::now()
         ]);

         // create badge
         $this->createCandidateBadge($candidate, $certificate);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
         // Response with Error here
    }
});
// Response with success
```

Also check this question [Laravel: Using try…catch with DB::transaction()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906844/laravel-using-try-catch-with-dbtransaction)

Enjoy :)