# Laravel Transactions dont work in Postgresql

Tags: laravel, postgresql, transactions, laravel-10

- Laravel: 10.3.3
- PostgreSQL 10.23

**SIMPLE CODE:**

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try{
    $parent = new Parent($postAttributes);
    if($parent ->save()){
        $child = new Child($postAttributes);
        $child->save(); <- Here fire exception purposely

       //anything else
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'email' => 'kayla@example.com',
            'status' => 1
        ]);
        
    }
}catch(Exception $ex){
    DB::rollback();
}

DB::commit();
```

In this case, **parent** model was **saved!** Child model fire exception but laravel, or postgres, **dont rollback** changes!

Someone can helps me?

Owwww... Wait ! Yes I've already tried `DB::transaction(function () {})` too !

- I expect transactions to be "rollback" when there is any error

Comment: What does the PostgreSQL log file tell you about the SQL that was received?

Answer (score 0):

reordering **beginTransaction()** and **commit()** works like below.

```
try
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $parent = new Parent($postAttributes);
    if($parent ->save())
    {
        $child = new Child($postAttributes);
        $child->save(); <- Here fire exception purposely

       //anything else
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'email' => 'kayla@example.com',
            'status' => 1
        ]);
    }
    DB::commit();
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    DB::rollback();
}
```

more explained on comment of this post by *alexrussell*
[Laravel: Using try...catch with DB::transaction()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906844/laravel-using-try-catch-with-dbtransaction)